# How to add addEventListener on particular clicked button?

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

I want to use `addEventListener()` on the clicked order button. What is the most efficient way of doing it? Here's how I'm doing it now:

```js
const executeUpdateSummary = (e) => {
  const classNameOfTargetedEl = event.target.className;
  
  if (classNameOfTargetedEl === ('order-button button')) {
    updateOrderSummary(e);
  }
};

const pizzasElement = document.querySelector('.pizzas');
pizzasElement.addEventListener('click', executeUpdateSummary, false);
```

```html
<div class="pizzas">
  <div class="menu-item">
    <div class="name">
      Margherita
    </div>
    <div class="price">Price: $5</div>
    <div class="toppings">Toppings:
      tomato
      mozzarella
    </div>
    <button class="order-button button" type="button">Add to order</button>
  </div>
  <div class="menu-item">
    <!-- There are multiple menu-items -->
  </div>
</div>
```

@MTCoster's answered what I was looking for:

```
const pizzaButtons = document.querySelectorAll('.order-button');

pizzaButtons.forEach(button => button.addEventListener('click', event => {
    updateOrderSummary(event);
}));
```

Comment: In your code you don't have the `event` parameter for `executeUpdateSummary`

Comment: I don't understand what you mean.  What exactly are you trying to do?  If you want that ***exact*** button, give it an `id` and use `getElementById` instead of getting it by class.  What is the problem you are facing?

Comment: @ConstantinChirila added `event` parameter for `executeUpdateSummary`

Comment: @zero298, can I do this without adding an id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not bind the event handler directly to the buttons? That way you don’t need to check the class in the event handler at all:

```js
const pizzaButtons = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.pizzas .order-button'));

pizzaButtons.forEach(btn => btn.addEventListener('click', event => {
  console.log('Updating order summary...');
  console.log('Clicked button:', event.target);
}));
```

```html
<div class="pizzas">
  <div class="menu-item">
    <div class="name">
      Margherita
    </div>
    <div class="price">Price: $5</div>
    <div class="toppings">Toppings:
      tomato
      mozzarella
    </div>
    <button class="order-button button" type="button">Add to order</button>
  </div><div class="menu-item">
    <div class="name">
      Pepperoni
    </div>
    <div class="price">Price: $7</div>
    <div class="toppings">Toppings:
      tomato
      mozzarella
      pepperoni
    </div>
    <button class="order-button button" type="button">Add to order</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Wouldn't that target only the first button (element with `order-button` class)?

Comment: Classes are reusable, IDs are not

Comment: I am not getting it. With your code, if I click on first button, I would see message in console. But if I click on second (or any button other than first) button, nothing would happen.